# The response of $http it's not the actual response but some previous one. And it's not cached

Tags: angularjs

I have a table where each row is a generated by `ng-repeat` from an array of data.
In one of the cells there is my directive that handles the remote fetching of data by a given url (from the array data).

My directive code:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="row" style="clear:both"></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attribute) {

        var fethRemoteContent = function () {
            $http.get(attribute.url).then(function (response) {

            console.log(response.data);

            // ...

        }

        $rootScope.$on('$TableHasBeenRefreshed', function () {
            return fethRemoteContent();
        });

        return fethRemoteContent();
    }
}
```

It works like a charm, except for the fact that when the event `$TableHasBeenRefreshed` is triggered, then the content of the response is not the actual uncached response, but the content of some other row previously fetched.  I verified that it is making the correct ajax call and getting the correct response in the inspector of Chrome.

My thoughts are about some kind of index? May be the `ng-repeat`? Maybe I have to destroy the variables (seems foolish, but still...)?

Comment: Can you expand your example a bit, at least including some of your HTML?

Comment: As it stands `fethRemoteContent` will always return undefined. Although you are missing a closing brace `}` from your example.